# Redirect from non-www to www on Heroku with PHP

Tags: php, redirect, heroku, dns, cname

I have a plain php app on Heroku, and per their recomendations I have my DNS for custom domain pointing to "www.biglikeco.com". Entering "biglikeco.com" doesn't point anywhere.

**What is the best way to redirect all traffic going to "biglikeco.com" to "www.biglikeco.com", in the context of a php app on Heroku?**

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using any framework?

Comment: First of all, if you want to do redirection, you will need to have DNS for `biglikeco.com` otherwise you won't be able to receive the request to rewrite it.

Comment: @MikeBrant, I messed with a couple things in the middle of the night but ended up bringing the site down for a while - I'm sure you can imagine the difficulty of "trial & error" with DNS TTL, etc. Can you point me in the right direction as to what record to put in DNS? I tried CNAME 'biglikeco.com' => 'www.biglikeco.com', also CNAME 'biglikeco.com' => 'myherokuapp.herokuapp.com'. Thanks

Comment: @MikeBrant also have SSL endpoint which compounds issue... I'm thinking the solution will be 1 part DNS record 1 partt .htaccess maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a generic PHP redirect script I created for you that you can append to any global include file you have that will do what you want:

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if (!preg_match('/^www\..*/', $host)) {
    header('location: http://www.my_site.com');
}
```

Or with .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my_site\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.my_site.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - the problem includes issues with getting all the 'biglikeco.com' traffic sent properly over DNS (compounded w/Heroku not digesting properly my SSL [which says 'www.biglikeco', and 'biglikeco.com']). I'm guessing the solution will include 1 part DNS record, and another part .htaccess?

Comment: Not sure.  Can you use .htaccess on Heroku?

Comment: Yes you can and php.ini if relevant...?

Comment: Ok, added .htaccess info for you

Comment: thanks much. any thoughts on getting the traffic routed there via dns? I tried CNAME 'biglikeco.com' => 'www.biglikeco.com', also CNAME 'biglikeco.com' => 'myherokuapp.herokuapp.com'. Also, have SSL endpoint enabled...

Comment: `biglikeco.com` should be your A record, and `www` should be your CNAME, pointing to `biglikeco.com`

Comment: don't `a` records have to be IPs?

Comment: Yes it does, Andypandy. But you can choose a random sharedhost for the A record to put up your .htaccess to do the redirect job.